# When a user clicks Sign Out, I would like to dismiss the View Controller to the first screen

Tags: ios, swift, dismiss

I'm creating a Login / Sign Up Flow, and upon clicking 'Sign Out' on the Table View Controller (last screen), I would like it to go back to the blue screen (which is the main app screen).

[image]

I am using the following code in my Table View Controller:

```
func signOutTapped (sender:UIButton) {
    PFUser.logOut()
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
}
```

Parse does successfully Sign the user out, and the screen dismisses to the previous screen (i.e. one of the green screens depending on where the user came from). However, when 'Sign Out' is clicked on the Table View Controller, I would like it to dismiss to the blue screen.

Should I be using a segue from the Table View Controller to the blue screen instead? If so, what type of segue would dismiss the screen via a slide down transition (opposite to a modal segue)?

Any advice on how to re-structure the storyboard would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Check out my answer here for a restructuring idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306905/best-way-to-conditionally-switch-root-view-controller-at-ios-app-start-up/31307295#31307295

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do it is this:
On completion of login or signup, dismiss the view-controller (green) back to the start screen(blue), and then present the tab-bar view-controller.

This would be a good pattern in general, because login/signup are optional tasks that aren't an inherent part of your app's workflow.
For instance, when a user is already signed-in (subsequent launches of the app), you would go straight from the blue screen (starting VC) to the tab-bar view-controller.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This did work, however, there's one issue. I added self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {}); before self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToFeed", sender: self) is called, and it closes the login window, and then opens the Table View Controller.  From a User Experience perspective, I would like it to open the Table View Controller first, and then close the Login View Controller in the background.  Any suggestions on how this can be accomplished?  Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could call `dismissViewControllerAnimated` false, and perform the segue? In a similar application that I built, I have in fact simply chained the two animations together, so that the login screen dismisses animated, and the next screen is presented, also animated.
This way, the role of the login view-controller is again emphasized as an in-between, optional task.

Answer (score 0):

try calling this function:

This will search for the top most `IUViewController` and dismiss all of it's presented view controllers.

```
func goHome() {
  var parent = self
  while parent.presentingViewController != nil {
    parent = parent.presentingViewController!
  }
  parent.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:nil)
}
```