# Black screen with viewDidLoad after if else statement

Tags: swift

I want my app to check at start conditionaly if a variable is correct or not. Based on that it should either go to an intro screen (where he can select a variable in my case select a team) or it should start the main view. After searching i found this code and edited it. But there still seems to be problems. First of all I dont have two identifier. The Intro has one but not the main view. My main View is called WeatherViewController and the Intro screen is called FirstScreenViewController. I also added a picture of my Main.storyboard.
I also googled a lot about conditional UINavigationController but I can only understand with a video and did not found a video about it.

I tried to use the code from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651854/display-a-particular-viewcontroller-in-xcode-swift-using-if-else-conditional-sta)

```
var id = hello ? "goToIntro" : "???"
  self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
  let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let WeatherViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.FirstScreenViewController(withIdentifier: WVC has no identifier??) as UIViewController
  self.window?.rootViewController = WeatherViewController
  self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
   if hello {
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToIntro", sender: self)
    } else {
/here nothing should happen. It should open the Main View
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "???", sender: self)
    }
```

[image: Main.Storyboard]

Comment: "Hello" was removed because Stack Overflow tries to avoid conversational language in posts. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: This answer was referring to the original question (before any edits) that was attempting a segue inside `loadView()`.

---

You're supposed to manually create your controller's view in `loadView`. You're currently doing nothing, hence the black screen. Furthermore, if you are using a Storyboard or a xib for managing this controller you shouldn't be overriding `loadView` at all.

Having said that it might be a better idea to move this branching logic a step back, to "something" (a container controller like a `UINavigationController` or a custom one, or even directly setting the root controller of your window if it makes sense) that will present (or set) A or B based on some condition and thus avoid to load this controller altogether (have in mind that in your code, the controller is initialized, it will be part of the hierarchy and all the lifecycle methods *will* be called even if you segued directly to another one)

Finally, if you decide for some reason to override `loadView` you don't have to call `viewDidLoad` yourself, the system will call this method.

Comment: The black screen only happens on the else statement. The If statement shows the correct View if the variable is right. Is it not possible to solve this without a UINavigationController? Can I not use a normal if else statement? If this then show View1 else show View2. I nearly know nothing about UINavigationController.

Comment: As I have explained, the screen is black because in the `else`, where this controller is to be presented, you _need_ to create and assign its `view`. If you don't (which is your case), nothing is displayed, hence the blackness. If you're using storyboards, you could move this logic to `viewWillAppear` but as I written in my answer I **wouldn't recommend this**.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. But it looks like i have some understanding problems. Can you link a youtube tutorial or somethings like that? I searched about UINavigationController but none of those videos I found showed an if/else statement.

Comment: @ahmetinho You're welcome, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651854/display-a-particular-viewcontroller-in-xcode-swift-using-if-else-conditional-sta) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306905/best-way-to-conditionally-switch-root-view-controller-at-ios-app-start-up) are some related answers. You can also try searching for "ios conditionally show controller" or something similar.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. I edited the post above. Can you please look at it?